# Java, need help making a for loop to make a image like stairs with single letters

Tags: java, for-loop

I need help to make program that will accept a number and print that number of rows to make a image, and it would use letters for the image like this. for example i will input the number 5 and then the program would print this.....

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
```

|

```
public class Stairs
{
    public static void Stairs1 (int height)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row = row + 1) 
        {
            for (int col = 0; col <= row; col = col + 1) 
            {
                System.out.print("x");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This is to make that. I'm trying to make the a simpler thing but it would be flipped over from the left side to the right side
like this.....

```
    x
   xx
  xxx
 xxxx
xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below; it should give you the desired output:

```
// Function to demonstrate printing pattern 
    public static void printStars(int n) 
    { 
        int i, j; 

        // outer loop to handle number of rows 
        //  n in this case 
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) 
        { 

            // inner loop to handle number spaces 
            // values changing acc. to requirement 
            for(j=2*(n-i); j>=0; j--) 
            { 
                // printing spaces 
                System.out.print(" "); 
            } 

            //  inner loop to handle number of columns 
            //  values changing acc. to outer loop 
            for(j=0; j<=i; j++) 
            { 
                // printing stars 
                System.out.print("* "); 
            } 

            // ending line after each row 
            System.out.println(); 
        } 
    } 

    // Driver Function 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int n = 5; 
        printStars(n); 
    } 
}
```